# method undefined for the type error

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have three different projects which has its java source files `DBHandler` (DBHandler.java)  `DataObject` (DataObject.java) and `LinkedIn` (LinkedIn.java)

`DBHandler` has a method `addLinkedInMessages(lpo)` which takes the dataObjects' object.

and my `LinkedIn` calls the method `addLinkedInMessages(lpo)`. Now I'm getting error

```
The method addLinkedInMessages(LinkedInPageObject) is undefined for
the type LinkedInDBHandler  LinkedInPageLoader.java
```

However here is my code in the `LinkedInDBHandler`

```
public ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject> getAllLinkedInUsersFromDatabase() {
        ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject> laoarray = new ArrayList<LinkedInAccountObject>();
        LinkedInAccountObject lao = new LinkedInAccountObject();

 return laoarray;     
}
```

I added the dependent projects to other projects build path. But I'm unable to call the newly created methods. However I'm able to use the existing methods.

Please any one help me

Comment: Could you share addLinkedInMessages() method? And are your classes have any dependency between each other?

Comment: The code you provide does not give a clue on your problem. Your are talking about `DBHandler.java` but the error is on `LinkedInDBHandler`. Please provide more information.

Comment: Sorry i just typed the project name instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I actually had the method addLinkedInMessages(LinkedInPageObect) in the LinkedInDBHandler.java file.

The project was added and also build created and added the jar file into the project. Removed the jar resolved it since the jar was exported when these methods was not added.

Thanks once again for everyone posted answer here

Answer (score 0):

You must add method `addLinkedInMessages(LinkedInPageObject)` which gets object of type `LinkedInPageObject`, to class `LinkedInDBHandler`.

Comment: the method is already available in the LinkedInDBHandler.java

Comment: Then if so, check the type of the parameters of your method. Maybe there is a mismatch.

Comment: Your exception suggests otherwise

Answer (score 0):

What this exception means is you don't have a method called `addLinkedInMessages` accepting an attribute of type `LinkedInPageObject` in class `LinkedInDBHandler`.

So in your `LinkedInDBHandler.java` you must include:

```
public void addLinkedInMessages(LinkedInPageObject linkedInPageObject)
//     ^--- > or the return type you need
```